# How to differentiate $ f(x) = (\csc \pi x)^{-4/5}$

Tags: derivatives

How can I  differentiate $ f(x) = (\csc \pi x)^{-4/5}$?

My problem is that there is a $\pi$ in the question and it's a constant so how is it supposed to be differentiated in the first place?

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take a simple example first so as to ease your confusion around $\pi$ being in the expression we want to differentiate.

Take $\sin(3x)$. I’m sure you’ll agree with me that the derivative of this with respect to $x$ is $3 \cos(3x)$. We can arrive at this using the chain rule, where after differentiating $\sin(x)$ we multiply by the derivative of $3x$ which is, of course, just $3$. Now replace the constant $3$ with $\pi$. There is no difference in technique—the derivative is $\pi \cos(\pi x)$.

Let’s tackle your real question. First note that $\frac{d}{dx} [\csc(x)] = -\cot(x)\csc(x)$.

We’ll apply the chain rule as we did above, repeatedly.

$$f(x) = (\csc(\pi x))^{\frac{-4}{5}}$$

$$f’(x) = \color{red}{ \frac{d}{dx} [(\csc(\pi x)^{\frac{-4}{5}})]}$$

$$ = \frac{-4}{5} \csc(\pi x)^{\frac{-9}{5}} \cdot \color{red}{ \frac{d}{dx} [\csc(\pi x)]}$$

$$= \frac{-4}{5} \csc(\pi x)^{\frac{-9}{5}} \cdot -\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi x) \cdot \color{red}{ \frac{d}{dx} [\pi x]}$$

$$= \frac{-4}{5} \csc(\pi x)^{\frac{-9}{5}} \cdot -\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi x) \cdot \pi$$

which rearranges to give

$$f’(x) = \frac{4}{5} \pi \csc(\pi x)^{\frac{-9}{5}} \csc(\pi x) \cot(\pi x)$$

There is no problem with $\pi$ being within the $\csc$ function here; we can treat it like any other constant.

Answer (score 2):

It may help if you think of the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = (\csc \pi x)^{-4/5}$ as the composition of three separate function:
$$
f(x)=(\csc \pi x)^{-4/5} = g(h(j(x))
$$
where
$$
g(x) = x^{-4/5} \\
h(x) = \csc x\\
j(x) = \pi x
$$

By the chain rule,

$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x) = f'(g(x)\cdot g'(x).
$$

Hence, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} (\csc \pi x)^{-4/5} &= \frac{d}{dx} g(h(j(x))\\
&=g'\left(h(j(x)\right)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(h(j(x))\right) \\
&= g'(h(j(x))\cdot h'(j(x)) \cdot j'(x)
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} (\csc \pi x)^{-4/5} &=
\frac{-4}{5} \left(\csc \pi x\right)^{-9/5}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left( \csc \pi x\right) \\ 
&= \frac{4}{5} \left(\csc \pi x\right)^{-9/5}\cdot \csc \pi x\cot \pi x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (\pi x) \\
&= \frac{4\pi}{5} \left(\csc \pi x\right)^{-9/5}\cdot  \csc \pi x\cot \pi x 
\end{align}

Comment: You dropped a negative in your second to last step. Check d/dx ( csc pi x )

Answer (score 1):

$\csc'(x)=-\csc x \cot x$.  Now use the chain rule:   $\dfrac{4\pi}5(\csc \pi x)^{-\dfrac 95}\csc \pi x\cot \pi x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that the derivative is linear with respect to multiplication by a constant, that is;

$$\frac{d}{dx}\alpha f(x)=\alpha\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$

For any constant $\alpha$ and differentiable function $f(x)$.

Using the chain rule and this linearity, you then have;

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}cosec(\pi x)=-cosec(\pi x)cot(\pi x)\frac{d}{dx}(\pi x)=-\pi cosec(\pi)\cot(x)
\end{align*}

Then you can use the chain rule again to find the derivative you're after.